# What constitutes 'redundant delegate creation'?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I was registering to an event in my class, and as per usual I was lazy and just use the autocomplete feature built into Visual Studio 2008 Pro which auto creates the delegate creation and it's associated method.

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    protected event EventHandler<MyValueChangedArgs> MyValueChanged;

    protected FooBase()
    {
        MyValueChanged +=
            new EventHandler<MyValueChangedArgs>(HandleMyValueChanged);
    }

    private void HandleMyValueChanged(object sender, MyValueChangedArgs e)
    {
        // Some handling logic
    }
}
```

Usually I dont think twice when Visual Studio gens the event handler for me, but then I received a recommendation from Refactor! Pro to "Remove Redundant Delegate Creation". The recommendation results in:

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    protected event EventHandler<MyValueChangedArgs> MyValueChanged;

    protected FooBase()
    {
        MyValueChanged += HandleMyValueChanged;
    }

    private void HandleMyValueChanged(object sender, MyValueChangedArgs e)
    {
        // Some handling logic
    }
}
```

Under what circumstances is delegate creation redundant and when is delegate creation appropriate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that Refactor! tells you that the line

```
MyValueChanged += new EventHandler<MyValueChangedArgs>(HandleMyValueChanged);
```

Can be shortened and the compiler will infer a event handler creation and the TEventArgs type argument...

> Under what circumstances is delegate
>   creation redundant and when is
>   delegate creation appropriate?

On designer-generated code...

Answer (score 6):

Sorry about that.  We just didn't have time in the product schedule to generate the shorter code when anonymous methods were added to C#.

I always edit the generated code to remove the extra syntax.